# Chrome extension says "Wants access to this site"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My Chrome extension's `manifest.json` contains the following sections:

```
"permissions": [
  "activeTab",
  "webNavigation",
  "webRequest",
  "webRequestBlocking",
  "*://example.com/*",
  "*://*.example.com/*"
],

"content_scripts": [
    {
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "matches": [
        "*://example.com/*",
        "*://*.example.com/*"
      ],
      "all_frames": true,
      "match_about_blank": true,
      "js": [ "scripts/init.js" ]
    }
  ]
```

so it operates only on a single domain name *(e.g.)* `example.com`

---

My `background.js` script contains the following code:

```
async function setIcon(tabId, path) {
  // based on several parameters show the icon in different colors
  // calls chrome.browserAction.setIcon with customized imageData
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
  if (changeInfo && (changeInfo.status === 'loading') && (tabId === tab.id)) {
    setIcon(tabId, (tab.url != undefined) ? '../icons/active/scalable.svg' :
                                            '../icons/inactive/scalable.svg');
  }
});
```

which switches the extension icon between grayed (inactive) and colored (active) based on the matching URL of the tab.

---

When the tab shows the content of the **matching** URL document, the icon is colored (active) and when I hover my mouse over this icon, the tooltip says "**Has access to this site**".

When the tab shows the content of the **non-matching** URL document, the icon is grayed (inactive) and when I hover my mouse over this icon, the tooltip says "**Wants access to this site**".

Why does the tooltip say that the extension wants access to a non-matching site *(e.g. https://stackoverflow.com)* when it is not true? This surely confuses users. Can I prevent such a message from being shown?

Comment: tabId = tab.id - is this a typo? Don't you mean tabId == tab.id ?

Comment: You need to remove `activeTab` permission. This should also handle the icon color automatically so you won't even need onUpdated.

Answer (score 2):

I found out what causes this message.

It is the `webNavigation` permission. When this permission is added, such a message is shown.

Comment: Have same problem. I have 'activeTab' and 'scripting' permissions declared.
I am getting the message 'Wants access to this site'.

Don't know how to get rid of it.
Any ideas?

Thanx.